# Can I cast major image every day to make a new illusion?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can my 11th level Wizard cast major image at 6 level and make a new illusion once a day that lasts forever until dispelled?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Why is the level of the spell relevant? And when you asked about "making duplicates of myself," are you expecting the illusions to be able to do the things you can do (cast spells, do damage, etc.)? Also, when you say "can only be killed with dispel Magic [sic]", are you implying that nothing else could end your illusion?

Comment: That seems to be within the basic functionality of the spell. Is there a reason you think you couldn't, or is there some specific thing you expect these images to do?

Comment: I didn't imply that I wanted the images to do anything. Why would you assume otherwise?

Comment: 11th level is when you get your first six level slot

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted the images to do something: I was unsure whether you meant "duplicates of myself" to mean just an image of yourself, or another of yourself (in every other sense).

Comment: Asking you what you're trying to do is the opposite of "assuming otherwise".

Comment: The question as written suggests a desire to create a theme park using the PC's illusions to entertain the guests.  (Haunted Mansion, Disneyland, is what sprang to mind).  Is that your intention, or are you trying to solve a different problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the description:

> **At Higher Levels.** When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 6th level or higher, the spell lasts until dispelled, without requiring your concentration.

So yes, you can create as many illusions of yourself as you wish. Each of which can perform the same repetitive motions over and over. However,

- They are just illusions so they cannot perform any actions, cast any spells, move any objects etc. They are not clones.
- They are programmed to do a single range of motions. So if you make one that looks like it's pacing, it will always be pacing, even if someone tries to physically interrupt it. At least until you concentrate on it and give it a new loop.
- Once someone interacts with the images, they are seen to be illusions and become "faint" (as per the spell).
- You can't "kill" an illusion. They are not alive, nor have they ever been alive. The closest you could come is the Wizard Illusionist tradition, "Illusory Reality" where one could become "real" for one minute and it becomes an illusion again. But that only works on objects not "simulated people".

Comment: Note that Illusory Reality only works on objects.

Comment: @Szega, good point. I removed that part from the post.